# StatusBar in searchController and searchResultsController problems : iOS 8

Tags: ios8, appdelegate, uistatusbar, uisearchcontroller, uisearchresultscontroller

**Hi, here is my problem:**

In my AppDeleagate's  **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** method i have a method **[self configureUINavigationControllerStlyle];** which configures the status bar and all the navigation bar appearance of my app (I have UINavigationController and UITabbarController working together in my App).

```
-(void) configureUINavigationControllerStlyle {

UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [CustomColor getAwesomeColor:@"colorBlue3_1"]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance]  setTitleTextAttributes:@{
NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],
NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-DemiBold" size:17.0]
 }];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

}
```

**Also In my info.plist i set: View controller-based status bar appearance to "NO"**

Everything worked great and all the controllers inside my app have their status bars with blue background and white text color. But not the  uisearchcontroller and uisearchresultscontroller.

My root TableViewController looks like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oqcozos89x9yqhg/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-11%20at%2016.21.06.jpg?dl=0

I integrated searchController and searchResultsController in my app.
The logic works well, but I don't understand how to deal with status bar appearance inside searchController and searchResultController. They don't use styles for status bar that i created in my AppDelegate.m file.

My searchController and searchResultsController look like this (Statusbar became white and text color of the status bar also became white, but I need my status bar to be the same color as in my Home View Controller (blue background and white text color).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/26skdz7gvehmwl4/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-11%20at%2016.21.16.png?dl=0

Another bug:
When I use

```
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

in my AppDelegate - it causes "jumping or stretching down" of my home tableview at the moment of going back from detail view controller after using search controller. When I don't set translucent property - there is no "jumping" .

**Maybe anyone knows how to fix that status bar colours problems when using searchController in iOS 8.**

If I use default colours (don't add any changes to my AppDelegate), everything works fine, but I need custom status bar colours in my app.

Comment: it's a bug. see my workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30225864/235297

Answer (score 6):

You will need to subclass `UISearchController` and override `preferredStatusBarStyle` like so:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Comment: If all you're adding to the UISearchController subclass, you could also consider adding `preferredStatusBarStyle` as an extension.

Comment: Yes, extension works!```extension UISearchController {
 public override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
  return .LightContent
 }
}```

Answer (score 0):

If you want white text in your status bar, inside your `info.plist` make sure you have `Status bar style` set to `Opaque black style` or `Transparent black style`.

That should work with the rest of your code.