# Gap above UISearchBar using UISearchController

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm experiencing an odd behavior with the UISearchBar in iOS. My search bar was working fine:

[image: Good UISearchBar]

But when I set `UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false` in my ApplicationDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to get the colors right in the Navigation Bar in my iOS app, the search bar gets a white section above it like this:

[image: Broken UISearchBar]

When scrolling the results table view, the underlying content is visible in that gap:

[image: Broken UISearchBar translucent]

The closest I've gotten to fixing it, was setting `mySearchResultsViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None`, which stopped the translucent gap, but still doesn't have the right color:

[image: Broken UISearchBar edgesForExtendedLayout None]

Is there something I can do to prevent it from showing that discolored gap and still have globally opaque navigation bars?

Answer (score 6):

After much googling, I found the following answer buried in the search results: [UISearchController doesn't work properly with a non-translucent UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369239/uisearchcontroller-doesnt-work-properly-with-a-non-translucent-uinavigationbar)

Specifically, this snippet worked when I put it in the presenting view controller:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
}
```

So simple, yet difficult to guess.

Comment: It works, but why?