# UISearchController issues iOS8 vs iOS9

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I ran into a problem where the `UISearchController`, when it animates the `searchBar` into the `navigationBar`, leaves the `statusBar` transparent and not the same color as the `searchBar`, like below:

[image]

I searched SO, and the below solution inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369239/uisearchcontroller-doesnt-work-properly-with-a-non-translucent-uinavigationbar)

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}

- (void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

fixes the problem for iOS9, but **not for iOS8**. I tried setting

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

but with no effect. Also, setting

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
```

hides the initial `searchBar` under the `navigationBar`, so I cannot use it.

Here's my code for initiating a `UISearchController` under an opaque `UINavigationBar`:

```
UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;

self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0); // Required for iOS8, not iOS9 though

[self.view addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
```

Any suggestions how to **fix this for iOS8**?